# Angular Material 2 md-input changing un-focus text and under-line color

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to change md-input text color and line color when it is un-focused? For example I am using md-input on a dark background hence would like a white font and underline (see below). Note I would like to retain the default color for my other forms so ideally a solution that enables me to style the specific controls directly or a way to place a different theme on the inputs.

[image: Dark Background and Md Input]

Answer (score 2):

I have solved similar a problem with the method below.

html

```
 <md-input 
    (focus)="searhFocus()" 
    (blur)="searchUnfocus()" 
    [ngClass]="{'searchbar-unfocus': !searchFocused, 'searchbar-focus': searchFocused}">
 </md-input>
```

component.ts

```
  private searchFocused: boolean = false;
  searhFocus() {
    this.searchFocused = true;
  }
  searchUnfocus() {
    this.searchFocused = false;
  }
```

and css

```
.searchbar-focus{
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.searchbar-unfocus{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.16);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.38);
}
```

For the line, you can use `:host >>> .md-input-underline{...}`